# Average of Rectangle Area

Tags: java, average, area

I have to find the average sum of the areas of each rectangle. I can find the area of each rectangle, should I store each area into an array and find the average through that? or is that not possible?

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> list = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    list.add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 25, 50));
    list.add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 30));
    list.add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 40));
    list.add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 45 ));
    list.add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 13, 13));

    double aAvg = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ) {
        double h = list.get(i).getHeight();
        double w = list.get(i).getWidth();
        double area = h * w;
        System.out.println(area);
    }
```

Comment: Can't believe I overthought this...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just need to sum each area together

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ) {
    double h = list.get(i).getHeight();
    double w = list.get(i).getWidth();
    double area = h * w;
    sum += area;
}
```

Then calculate the average based off that value...

```
double aAvg = sum / (double)list.size();
```

Unless you need a list of the areas, there should be no need to maintain ANOTHER list.  Much simpler (and safer) to calculate it as you need it (in this case)...

Comment: Welcome to the forest, you won't see much for the trees ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> list = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    list.add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 25, 50));
    list.add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 30));
    list.add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 40));
    list.add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 45 ));
    list.add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 13, 13));

    double aAvg = 0.0;
    double totalArea = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ) {
        double h = list.get(i).getHeight();
        double w = list.get(i).getWidth();
        double area = h * w;
        totalArea += area;
        System.out.println(area);
    }
    aAvg = totalArea / list.size();

    System.out.println("Average area : " + aAvg);
```